# I need to know what size sub panel I need

Tags: garage, detached-structure

What size amp sub panel do I need to run off of a 100 amp main panel? At the moment I have a 100 amp sub panel hooked up and it’s making my drill spark and have a burning smell to it.

Comment: You have a different problem.  You need to take some pictures of the panel, and if possible, wires inside the panel, and we can figure out which of several problems it may be.

Comment: This isn't an amps problem...do you have a multimeter?

Comment: By the way, I know you're on the "I need a different subpanel" track but being on track X when the real problem is over at Y happens often enough we have a name for it: [The XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  No panel of any size should make a drill do that.  Let's take a look at it.  Also, do you have a voltmeter?  Or a "Kill-a-Watt" (that simply plugs into the wall), they are $20 at Walmart).

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. My husband got mad cuz he couldn’t figure it out and took everything back. Could you just give me an idea of what all I need to run electric from the house to the detached garage? Like what wire to use? Do I need a sub panel? If I need one what size do I need and what size breaker? The main panel in the house is only 100amp. Which I now everyone’s been updating to a 200 or a 250amp main box but with renting I can’t do that.